# tensor forest estimator value error at fitting the training part

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

Code :
    from sklearn import cross_validation as cv
    import numpy as np
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator
    from tensorflow.contrib.tensor_forest.python import tensor_forest

```
X = np.array([[  74.,  166.,  331.,  161.,  159.,  181.,  180.],
   [ 437.,  427.,  371.,  361.,  393.,  465.,  464.],
   [ 546.,  564.,  588.,  595.,  536.,  537.,  520.],
   [  89.,   89.,   87.,   87.,  108.,  113.,  111.],
   [  75.,   90.,   74.,   89.,  130.,  140.,  135.]])
Y = np.array([[ 51.,  43.,  29.,  43.,  43.,  41.,  42.],
   [ 22.,  23.,  26.,  27.,  25.,  19.,  19.],
   [  7.,   7.,   5.,   5.,   9.,   8.,  10.],
   [ 55.,  54.,  55.,  53.,  51.,  51.,  51.],
   [ 58.,  57.,  57.,  58.,  55.,  55.,  55.]])
train_X, test_X, train_Y, test_Y = cv.train_test_split(X, Y, 
test_size=0.50, random_state=42)

def build_estimator() :
 params = tensor_forest.ForestHParams(num_classes=7, num_features=7, 
 num_trees=30, max_nodes=100)
 graph_builder_class = tensor_forest.RandomForestGraphs

 graph_builder_class = tensor_forest.TrainingLossForest
 return estimator.SKCompat(random_forest.TensorForestEstimator(
   params, graph_builder_class=graph_builder_class,
   model_dir=None))
est = build_estimator() 
train_X = train_X.astype(dtype = np.float32) 
train_Y = train_Y.astype(dtype = np.float32) 
est = est.fit(x=train_X, y=train_Y, batch_size = 100)
```

My both input and output shape is [Number_of_samples,7]. It perfectly runs with scikitlearn random forest classifier. However for tf learn, I get the following error when fitting the estimator :

> INFO:tensorflow:Constructing forest with params = 
>   INFO:tensorflow:{'valid_leaf_threshold': 1, 'split_after_samples':
>   250, 'num_output_columns': 8, 'feature_bagging_fraction': 1.0,
>   'split_initializations_per_input': 1, 'bagged_features': None,
>   'min_split_samples': 5, 'max_nodes': 100, 'num_features': 7,
>   'num_trees': 30, 'num_splits_to_consider': 7, 'base_random_seed': 0,
>   'num_outputs': 1, 'dominate_fraction': 0.99, 'max_fertile_nodes': 50,
>   'bagged_num_features': 7, 'dominate_method': 'bootstrap',
>   'bagging_fraction': 1.0, 'regression': False, 'num_classes': 7}
>
> ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 est = est.fit(x=train_X, y=train_Y, batch_size = 100)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc
>   in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, steps, max_steps, monitors)    1351
>   steps=steps,    1352                         max_steps=max_steps,
>   -> 1353                         monitors=all_monitors)    1354     return self    1355
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/client/random_forest.pyc
>   in fit(self, x, y, input_fn, steps, batch_size, monitors, max_steps)
>       262     elif input is not None:
>       263       self._estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=steps, monitors=monitors,
>   --> 264                           max_steps=max_steps)
>       265     else:
>       266       raise ValueError('fit: Must provide either both x and y or input_fn.')
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.pyc
>   in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
>       278             _call_location(), decorator_utils.get_qualified_name(func),
>       279             func.**module**, arg_name, date, instructions)
>   --> 280       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       281     new_func.**doc** = _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(
>       282         func.**doc**, date, instructions)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc
>   in fit(self, x, y, input_fn, steps, batch_size, monitors, max_steps)
>       424       hooks.append(basic_session_run_hooks.StopAtStepHook(steps, max_steps))
>       425 
>   --> 426     loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
>       427     logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
>       428     return self
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc
>   in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks)
>       932       features, labels = input_fn()
>       933       self._check_inputs(features, labels)
>   --> 934       model_fn_ops = self._call_legacy_get_train_ops(features, labels)
>       935       ops.add_to_collection(ops.GraphKeys.LOSSES, model_fn_ops.loss)
>       936       all_hooks.extend([
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc
>   in _call_legacy_get_train_ops(self, features, labels)    1001     1002
>   def _call_legacy_get_train_ops(self, features, labels):
>   -> 1003     train_ops = self._get_train_ops(features, labels)    1004     if isinstance(train_ops, model_fn_lib.ModelFnOps):  # Default
>   signature    1005       return train_ops
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc
>   in _get_train_ops(self, features, labels)    1160       `ModelFnOps`
>   object.    1161     """
>   -> 1162     return self._call_model_fn(features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)    1163     1164   def
>   _get_eval_ops(self, features, labels, metrics):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc
>   in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode)    1131     if
>   'model_dir' in model_fn_args:    1132       kwargs['model_dir'] =
>   self.model_dir
>   -> 1133     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features, labels, **kwargs)    1134     1135     if isinstance(model_fn_results, model_fn_lib.ModelFnOps):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/client/random_forest.pyc
>   in _model_fn(features, labels)
>       128     if labels is not None:
>       129       training_loss = graph_builder.training_loss(
>   --> 130           features, labels, name=LOSS_NAME)
>       131       training_graph = control_flow_ops.group(
>       132           graph_builder.training_graph(
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/python/tensor_forest.pyc
>   in training_loss(self, features, labels, name)
>       559 
>       560   def training_loss(self, features, labels, name='training_loss'):
>   --> 561     return array_ops.identity(self._get_loss(features, labels), name=name)
>       562 
>       563
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/python/tensor_forest.pyc
>   in _get_loss(self, features, labels)
>       548     self._loss = control_flow_ops.cond(
>       549         self.average_size() > 0, _average_loss,
>   --> 550         lambda: constant_op.constant(sys.maxsize, dtype=dtypes.float32))
>       551 
>       552     return self._loss
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.pyc
>   in cond(pred, fn1, fn2, name)    1757     context_t =
>   CondContext(pred, pivot_1, branch=1)    1758     context_t.Enter()
>   -> 1759     orig_res, res_t = context_t.BuildCondBranch(fn1)    1760     context_t.ExitResult(res_t)    1761     context_t.Exit()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.pyc
>   in BuildCondBranch(self, fn)    1658   def BuildCondBranch(self, fn): 
>   1659     """Add the subgraph defined by fn() to the graph."""
>   -> 1660     r = fn()    1661     original_r = r    1662     result = []
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/python/tensor_forest.pyc
>   in _average_loss()
>       544       probs = self.inference_graph(features)
>       545       return math_ops.reduce_sum(self.loss_fn(
>   --> 546           probs, labels)) / math_ops.to_float(array_ops.shape(labels)[0])
>       547 
>       548     self._loss = control_flow_ops.cond(
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/python/tensor_forest.pyc
>   in _loss(probs, targets)
>       508   def _loss(probs, targets):
>       509     if targets.get_shape().ndims > 1:
>   --> 510       targets = array_ops.squeeze(targets, squeeze_dims=[1])
>       511     one_hot_labels = array_ops.one_hot(
>       512         math_ops.to_int32(targets),
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.pyc
>   in squeeze(input, axis, name, squeeze_dims)    2270   if
>   np.isscalar(axis):    2271     axis = [axis]
>   -> 2272   return gen_array_ops._squeeze(input, axis, name)    2273     2274
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.pyc
>   in _squeeze(input, squeeze_dims, name)    3496   """    3497   result
>   = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Squeeze", input=input,
>   -> 3498                                 squeeze_dims=squeeze_dims, name=name)    3499   return result    3500
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.pyc
>   in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
>       761         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
>       762                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
>   --> 763                          op_def=op_def)
>       764         if output_structure:
>       765           outputs = op.outputs
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc
>   in create_op(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs,
>   op_def, compute_shapes, compute_device)    2395
>   original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)    2396     if
>   compute_shapes:
>   -> 2397       set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)    2398     self._add_op(ret)    2399
>   self._record_op_seen_by_control_dependencies(ret)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc
>   in set_shapes_for_outputs(op)    1755       shape_func =
>   _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op    1756 
>   -> 1757   shapes = shape_func(op)    1758   if shapes is None:    1759     raise RuntimeError(
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc
>   in call_with_requiring(op)    1705     1706   def
>   call_with_requiring(op):
>   -> 1707     return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)    1708     1709   _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op =
>   call_with_requiring
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.pyc
>   in call_cpp_shape_fn(op, input_tensors_needed,
>   input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, debug_python_shape_fn,
>   require_shape_fn)
>       608     res = _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed,
>       609                                   input_tensors_as_shapes_needed,
>   --> 610                                   debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
>       611     if not isinstance(res, dict):
>       612       # Handles the case where _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl calls unknown_shape(op).
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.pyc
>   in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed,
>   input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, debug_python_shape_fn,
>   require_shape_fn)
>       673       missing_shape_fn = True
>       674     else:
>   --> 675       raise ValueError(err.message)
>       676 
>       677   if missing_shape_fn:
>
> **ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 7
>   for 'cond/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,7].**

Comment: Would you mind including some fake data which reproduces the issue in your question (i.e. make the code snippet self-contained)?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, when using TrainingLossForest it assumes a classification problem.  I will fix this internally, but for now you can get around it with something like:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.losses.python.losses import loss_ops

def _loss_fn(values, targets):
  return loss_ops.mean_squared_error(values, targets)

def _builder_class(params, **kwargs):
  return tensor_forest.TrainingLossForest(
      params, loss_fn=_loss_fn, **kwargs)

TensorForestEstimator(..., graph_builder_class=_builder_class)
```

Or whatever loss function you want (MSE here as example).  Also, simply using (`graph_builder_class = tensor_forest.RandomForestGraphs`) should suffice, but the loss is the number of nodes, so training stops when the forest stops growing or reaches max_nodes, which is maybe not what you want.